# Could not find package api-platform/api-pack in a version matching 2.2

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

When i run the `composer req api-platform "^2.2"` command, i get the following message.

[image: cmd message]

As first i thought it may be the symfony version, that could not be compatible with api 2.2. But it does not seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message says that there isn't 2.2 version of api-platform package yet. The latest version now is 2.1.6. You can make sure here: https://packagist.org/packages/api-platform/api-platform. So, composer couldn't include any package according your rules

**Generally about packages versions sintax:**

1. If you want specific version use *1.2.3*
2. If you have some range use *>1.2.3 < 1.3*
3. *Sign ~1.2.3* means that you agree to any version until 1.3 (not including 1.3)
4. *Sign ^1.2.3* means that you agree to any version until 2.0 (not including 2.0)
5. If you want get last available version use 1.2.* (not including 1.3) or 1.* (not including 2.0)

**Solution:**
So, if you want to get last available version up to 2.2 use

```
composer req api-platform "~2.1.6"
```

**Source:** 
http://fkn.ktu10.com/?q=node/9859

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Anyways, it won't find any version from 1.2

Comment: Ok, you are rigth. Maybe the problem in package name? I saw "api-platform/api-platform" package on packagist.org. Do you need "api-platform/api-pack"? Like here: https://api-platform.com/docs/distribution/#using-symfony-flex-and-composer-advanced-users.

They offer require package without version:
`composer req api`

Comment: Uhm... In "api-platform.com" i saw in the documentation that the current version is 2.4.

So, from that, i am trying to install it. But my api-platform/api-pack version is at 1.2.0 as higher, and my api-platform/core version is at 2.2.9. 

I am pretty lost, because i think there are some features i cant use because of this problem

Comment: Just try to use 1.2. And ask the question about problems you'll have. Maybe the reason is different.